# October CMS: URL redirected to 404 page on first time

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins

When I am calling to my october cms [Multi Lang] created website . When I call first time or when i change language it first time shows 404 page. and next time it runs well.

Comment: may be caching issue, can you try in `incognito mode` and check this if its persist or not.

Comment: @HardikSatasiya No dear, I solved, Its related to plugin changes.

Comment: ok thanks, good to hear its solved .. best of luck :)